# configure knexfile.js using aws secret manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, knex.js, aws-secrets-manager

I need to configure the knexfile.js using the secrets retrieve from the secret manager.
I retrieve the secrets from secret manager and stores it in secret variable and use it in configuration.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
endpoint = "abcd",
region = "us-east-1",
secretName = "abcd",
secret,
binarySecretData;

var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
endpoint: endpoint,
region: region
});
client.getSecretValue({
SecretId: secretName
}, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
if (err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException')
    console.log("The requested secret " + secretName + " was not found");
else if (err.code === 'InvalidRequestException')
    console.log("The request was invalid due to: " + err.message);
else if (err.code === 'InvalidParameterException')
    console.log("The request had invalid params: " + err.message);
} else {
if (data.SecretString !== "") {
    secret = data.SecretString;
} else {
    binarySecretData = data.SecretBinary;
}
}
});
module.exports = {
development: {
    client: secret.localClient,
    connection: {
        host: secret.localHost,
        user: secret.localUser,
        password: secret.localPassword,
        database: secret.localDatabase,
        charset: "utf8"
    }
},
};
```

But it shows an error
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'localClient' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in Knex. You can pass an async function to the `configuration`.

```
async function getConfig() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: 'SECRETID' }, function(
    err,
    data
  ) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('secretsErr', err);
      reject(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Secrets Manager call successful');
      if ('SecretString' in data) {
        let secret = data.SecretString;
        secret = JSON.parse(secret);
        const config = {
          user: secret.DbUser,
          password: secret.DbPassword,
          server: secret.DbServer,
          database: secret.DbDatabase,
          expirationChecker: () => false,
          options: {
            encrypt: true,
            enableArithAbort: true
          }
        };
        resolve(config);
      } else {
        console.log('no secret found');
        reject();
      }
    }
  });
}

let knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: async function() {
    return await getConfig();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting secret is asynchronous operation, so your variable `secret` it doesn't exist yet when you are trying to export it from knexfile.js.

You probably should first fetch secret to be stored somewhere locally, when starting up virtual machine and then in knexfile.js read it synchronously for example from local file.

Comment: Thank you **Mikael** , but how to call the function `client.getSecretValue()` synchronously ?

Comment: I would do it in a separate initialization script before running `npm start` for the actual application.

Comment: I fall into the same issue. but my biggest problem is I am using this with serverless lambda. I come up with that there is no solution to support load the config from aws secret manager especially if we need to run the migrations from Knex cmd :(

Comment: In that case you need to wrap migration client to script, which first fetches secrets / knex config and only after that tries to run the migrations.